# How to lock select columns in worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In a sheet (named "JE") I have two columns E & G that have formulas in them and want to ONLY lock those columns. When I try to click format --> Lock Cells then protect the sheet, it protects all of the columns. Is there a way through the front end in excel or VBA, where I can **only** lock those two columns and that's it?

The version I am working with is MS Excel 2016.

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Excel?  Feel free to update your question with this as it could effect the steps to accomplish.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I have updated my question with the version I am working with. Thanks

Comment: Just select ALL the cells in your sheet, untick "Locked" on them, then re-tick "Locked" on the cells you want to protect and protect the sheet.  (Every version of Excel I've used has had "Locked" ticked by default in the standard blank workbook.)

Comment: @tjejojyj when I highlight the cells in columns E & G that I want to lock, I go to format, format cells, check "locked" then I protect the sheet. After I protect the sheet, I want to be able to edit column F but when I try, I get an error message saying that the sheet is protected and I can't click into that cell. How can I lock just the E & G columns, and that's it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select ALL the cells in your sheet, untick "Locked" on them, then re-tick "Locked" only on the cells/columns that you want to protect and protect the sheet.

(Every version of Excel I've used has had "Locked" ticked by default in the standard blank workbook.)